# Find the Wrong Student

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

There are 15 student in the class and each of them has a different number 1 to 15.

- Student #1: wrote the natural number on the board.
- Student #2 said : This number is divisible by my number(number 2)
- Student #3 said : This number is divisible by my number(number 3)
- Student #4 said : This number is divisible by my number ( Number 4)

And so on until

- Student #15 said : This number is divisible by my number ( Number 15 )

Student #1 is verifying the other 14 student said and he finds that all of them said it correctly except for two student with consecutive numbers. 
What is the sum of these two consecutive numbers?

Comment: This looks impossible to me. No number between 1 and 15 can have 12 different divisors.

Comment: I think the number written on the board is just some natural number, possibly very large.

Comment: Hahaha xD same here but the answer key is #8 and #9 which the answer 17

Comment: If @Shagnik is correct, do we know which number student #1 (which made no claim) has?

Comment: I think the #1 student write a Natural which can divisible by number 2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14 and 15 but not 8 and 9

Comment: Natural number **

Comment: For example, if student #1 is thinking of $14$ and the two lying students are thinking of $7$ and $8$, then the number on the blackboard might be $4\cdot 9\cdot 5\cdot  11\cdot 13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $17$, as students number $8$ and $9$ are wrong.

To see this, note that if student $i$ is wrong, then student $ki$ must be wrong for every $k \ge i$.  As these will not be two consecutive numbers, this cannot be the case.  This means students $2$ through $7$ must be right.

Given $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ coprime, if student number $pq$ is wrong, then either $p$ or $q$ must be wrong as well.  (In other words, if $pq | n$, then both $p | n$ and $q | n$.)  However, these would not form two consecutive students.  This means $10$, $12$, $14$ and $15$ are right as well.

This leaves $8$ and $9$ as the only consecutive pair that could both be wrong.

Comment: How can we know that the number must be divisible by 4 or 8 and 7 or 14?

Comment: Since $4$ and $8$ are not consecutive, those two students cannot both have been wrong.  Hence at least one of them are right, and hence the number is divisible by either $4$ or $8$.  However, if it is divisible by $8$, then it is also divisible by $4$, so it *must* be divisible by $4$.  The same argument works for $7$ and $14$.

Answer (score 0):

The number must either be divisible by $4$ or by $8$ and either by $7$ or by $14$, because these are non-consecutive, hence it is divisible by $4$ and by $7$. This excludes $2,3,4,7$. In particular, it is divisible by $6$, so all of $2,3,4,5,6,7$ are divisors as well. Thus, it is also divisible by $10$, $12$ and by $15$ and so it is also divisible by $11$ and by $13$.

This leaves only one possibility: $(8,9)$. So the sum is $17$.